# Python Mechanize for form with options populated by Javascript

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to grab prices for New York's metro-north railroad from this site: http://as0.mta.info/mnr/fares/choosestation.cfm

The problem is that when you select the first option, the site uses javascript to populate your list of possible destinations. I have written equivalent code in python, but I can't seem to get it all working. Here's what I have so far:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1)     Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open("http://as0.mta.info/mnr/fares/choosestation.cfm")

br.select_form(name="form1")
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

origin_control = br.form.find_control("orig_stat", type="select")
origin_control_list = origin_control.items
origin_control.value = [origin_control.items[0].name]

destination_control_list = reFillList(0, origin_control_list)

destination_control = br.form.find_control("dest_stat", type="select")
destination_control.items = destination_control_list
destination_control.value = [destination_control.items[0].name]

response = br.submit()
response_text = response.read()
print response_text
```

I know I didn't give you code for the reFillList() method, because it's long, but assume it correctly creates a list of mechanize.option objects. Python doesn't complain about me about anything, but on submit I get the html for this alert:

"Fare information for travel between two lines is not available on-line.  Please contact our Customer Information Center at 511 and ask to speak to a representative for further information."

Am I missing something here? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

It can't really be done without trying to make sense of the crazy logic in that function. I suggest a js solution or a full browser like selenium.